# Modeling quesion, linear regression or survival analysis

Tags: regression, survival, modeling, econometrics, model

I am analyzing a dataset where the **outcome** variable is "t*eenagers' recreational drug use in weeks*." This is continuous and highly skewed outcome variable. While the range spans from 2 weeks to 100 weeks, most teenagers reported experimenting with drugs for durations between 2 and 25 weeks, with very few values beyond 25 weeks.

This dataset comprises around 2000 children, **each with a single row of data**. There are no repeated measures; *each child enters the study at a different time*.

The **exposure** of interest is a single event: the abolition of a drug counselor position by the federal government in 2020.

The **goal** of the analysis is to examine **changes in drug use duration** ***before*** 2020, prior to the abolition of drug counselors, compared to ***after*** 2020, following the abolition.

My question is what is a appropriate model to analyze such outcome. Should I apply simple linear model or survival analysis ? I welcome any advice on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"This dataset comprises around 2000 children, each with a single row of data"* Each child has a row of data? Like what data?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, age, sex, education, parent's income, BMI, city, state, `before/after 2020`

Answer (score 2):

If there are no repeated measures, I suppose it means that you are not following the children in time, i.e. weeks of recreational drug use is an endpoint measure.
A survival analysis would not be appropriate, because your outcome variable is not the occurrence of an event. It would work if it were time to drug use for example.

I would first check that the time spent in the study does not differ between the 2 conditions (before the suppression of the counselor position and after). Then I would analyse it with a GLM, probably for a binomial distribution since it is skewed count data, but this depends how skewed the distribution of the outcome variable is.